# Finding gcd using euclid's algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Find $\gcd(47,6)$ using euclid's algorithm

I know that if $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(b,r)$ where $a=qb+r$

So in there case $47=7\cdot6+5$ or $47=8\cdot6-1$ should I prefer finding prime numbers decomposition? will it make the process shorter?

Comment: In this very particular case it's easy to see that $6=2\cdot 3$ and neither factor divides $47$ so the $\gcd$ is $1$. Don't expect that to always work out quickly in general, though.

Comment: Finding $$ \gcd(10972771937,10972981423)=104743 $$ takes $3$ iterations of the Euclidean Algorithm. Factoring $10972771937=104743\cdot104759$ or $10972981423=104743\cdot104761$ might take a bit of effort.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the cases where prime factor decomposition is readily available, Euclid's algorithm should be preferred, as it is much more computational efficient. Euclid's algorithm is [at most linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) in the number of digits of the smaller number $O(\log n)$, while integer factorization is a notoriously harder problem, [best published running time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) is $O\left(exp\sqrt[3]{\frac{64}{9}\log n (\log\log n)^2}\right)$. The difficulty of integer factorization is the basis for the RSA public key algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is to find GCD, you can use the one you find will get you quicker to the answer. If they want you to find two numbers such that $ax+by=gcd(a,b)$, then you have to use Euclid's algorithm..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the initial numbers are. Try $\gcd(F_{n + 1}, F_n)$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number.

Generally, though, the Euclidean algorithm is faster, or it's just a tiny bit slower than prime factorization so that the performance penalty is hardly worth being concerned about.

In the specific case of $\gcd(47, 6)$, prime factorization seems faster only because we already know 47 is prime and 6 is a semiprime, so it feels like we immediately know the two numbers are coprime.

It seems to me like the Euclidean algorithm is usually implemented to first do $\frac{a}{b}$ with $a > b$ and both numbers positive. So after $47 = 7 \times 6 + 5$, we do $6 = 1 \times 5 + 1$ and there we have our answer in two steps.

Now try $\gcd(100459, 14351)$. I have a feeling Euclid's algorithm gives you the answer in two steps. To find if 100459 is prime, you might have to do 316 trial divisions.